# Additional tables to list

Tags: php, mysql

My last question was answered for building a list from two tables.

```
SELECT CONCAT( P.LastName, ', ', P.FirstName ) AS Name, MP.MembershipID, P.PersonID
FROM `person` P
INNER JOIN `membershipperson` MP ON MP.PersonID = P.PersonID
ORDER BY MP.MembershipID DESC
```

Now I need help with adding additional information to the list.

1. I need a list that shows *LastName, FirstName, PersonID, MemberID, LastActiveYear, MemberSince, Approved, LockedOut*.
2. sql code set *Approved* bit to 0 if *LastActiveYear* is < 2013. I may want to use a php mysqli page for this one so I can change the year as required.

Here are the tables examples;

```
person  
PersonID      LastName    FirstName   
----------+------------+------------+---------
1212            Barr       Foo            
888             To         Go              
1415            From       Is             


Membershipperson 
MemberShipID      PersonID
-------------+------------  
 2250          1212
 1150           888
 3500          1415

users  
PersonID      Username    IsApproved   LockedOut
----------+-------------+-----------+-----------
1212           2250          1            1
888            1150          1            0
1415           3500          0            1

membership
MemberShipId             LastActiveYear
---------------+------------------------
    ####       +          2012
```

Corrected and added tables.

Comment: Are you wanting to update the table, or add more info to a php array, or...? Sorry, it's not quite clear what you're after.

Comment: First off I need to get a list of those members who  have a LastActiveYear less than 2013 and where the Approved bit is 1. After that I need to update all those on the list and set Approved bit to 0. I hope that is clears it up!  THANK YOU.

Comment: @BobCooper [**See updated fiddle here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15429/2)

Comment: I tried the sql query you created and it didn't fail but the query never ends. I can't get out of it now. I have logged out 3 times and can't log into the db any longer. I will have to wait it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you'll be using php mysqli

```
//Obviously substitute for you mysql credentials
$mysqli_link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pas") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli_link));
//again choose the correct right db
mysqli_select_db($mysqli_link,"database") or die (mysqli_error($mysqli_link));


$query = "SELECT CONCAT( P.LastName, ', ', P.FirstName ) AS Name, MP.MembershipID, ms.LastActiveYear, P.PersonID as personId
FROM `person` P
INNER JOIN `membershipperson` MP ON MP.PersonID = P.PersonID
LEFT JOIN `user` ON P.PersonID=users.PersonID
LEFT JOIN `membership` ms ON MP.MemberShipID=ms.MemberShipID
WHERE users.Approved=1
AND ms.LastActiveYear < 2013
ORDER BY MP.MembershipID DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli_link, $query);

//To see results
$data = array();
$ids = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
    $ids[] = $row['personId'];

}

echo'<pre>';
print_r($data);
die('</pre>'); // this will stop the rest of the page from loading

//loop through the results and store the `PersonID`'s in an array called `$ids` (or whatever you want to call it)

$ids = implode(',', $ids);
$ids = substr($ids, 0, -1);
$query = "UPDATE users SET Approved=0 WHERE PersonID IN ($ids)";
mysqli_query($mysqli_link, $query);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi and thank you Ross,  I tried the sql code and get an error as LastActiveYear is not in the users table, it is in the person table.

Comment: I put `P.LastActiveYear < 2013`?? Was the error with the first or second query?

Comment: Error
SQL query: Documentation

SELECT CONCAT( P.LastName,  ', ', P.FirstName ) AS Name, MP.MembershipID, P.PersonID
FROM  `person` P
INNER JOIN  `membershipperson` MP ON MP.PersonID = P.PersonID
LEFT JOIN  `users` ON P.PersonID = users.PersonID
WHERE users.Approved =1
AND P.LastActiveYear <2013
ORDER BY MP.MembershipID DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30

MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'P.LastActiveYear' in 'where clause'

Comment: Is field is definitely called `LastActiveYear` in your table?

Comment: I just realized the error. The LastActiveYear is not in table person it is in a table called "membership'. I'm real sorry about that. Not good when the info I supply is wrong.

Comment: It probably would if I new how to change it. I'm sure I would get it time. Thanks again

Comment: Do I require another INNER JOIN for this 'membership' table?

Comment: Ross works fine... Great.. How would I show the last active year in the list and the Approved bit. Do I need an additional SELECT as a sub ?

Comment: To show the last active year just add `ms.LastActiveYear` after P.PersonID so `P.PersonID, ms.LastActiveYear FROM`. As for the second query...I assume you're looping through the results from the first query in a `foreach` or `while` loop?

Comment: For the second query I could do that or build an array of the PersonID #'s. First wanted a list to look at. It is likely going to be 700 lines long. I want to be sure of who is on the list before I boot them. For some reason the system stopped resetting this after 2011?

Comment: I was asking if you had already created the loop? Also, is this just a one-off thing you want to do?

Comment: SELECT CONCAT( P.LastName,  ', ', P.FirstName ) AS Name, MP.MembershipID, P.PersonID, msLastActiveYear FROM .... error Unknown column 'msLastActiveYear' in 'field list'.  Worked fine until I added the msLastActiveYear

Comment: Loop is not created...One time deal.

Comment: ms.LastActiveYear you need the '.' ms is the name you have given to membership table ``membership` ms`. I've updated my answer to show the changes if you are happy with the list just remove the echo, print_r, die bit.

Comment: I will try this on a php page tomorrow. The boss is calling me :) TNX ROSS!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that  you asked for

- *I need a list that shows LastName, FirstName, PersonID, MemberID, LastActiveYear, MemberSince, Approved, LockedOut.From comments I need to get a list of those members who have a LastActiveYear less than 2013 and where the Approved bit is 1*

Here you go join your persons table  membership table and users table i guess you have maintained one - to - one relation

```
SELECT 
p.LastName,
p.FirstName,
p.PersonID, 
m.MemberID, 
p.LastActiveYear, 
p.MemberSince, 
u.Approved,
u.LockedOut
FROM person p
INNER JOIN Membershipperson m ON(m.PersonID = p.PersonID)
INNER JOIN users u ON(u.PersonID = u.PersonID)
INNER JOIN membership ms ON(ms.MembershipId = m.MemberID)
WHERE ms.LastActiveYear < '2013'
AND u.Approved =1
GROUP BY u.PersonID
```

Second you asked for

- *sql code set Approved bit to 0 if LastActiveYear is < 2013. I may want to use a php mysqli page for this one so I can change the year as required.*

Same as join your tables in update query and set Approved  to 0

```
UPDATE users u
INNER JOIN Membershipperson m ON(m.PersonID = u.PersonID)
INNER JOIN  person p ON(p.PersonID = u.PersonID)
INNER JOIN membership ms ON(ms.MembershipId = m.MemberID)
SET u.Approved = 0
WHERE ms.LastActiveYear < '2013'
```

<kbd>[**See Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/521736/1)</kbd>
<kbd>[**Updated Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15429/2)</kbd>

Comment: Hi... and thanks for the response. I tried the first code and get an error Membershipperson' doesn't exist at first INNER JOIN. Do I need to add something to 'membershipperson' for ident?

Comment: Do you have a table named `Membershipperson` ? if not then put right table name in query which contains the realtion of both users and persons

Comment: OK yes there is a table by that name, (Membershipperson) It has the cross referances for PersonID and MembershipID numbers.

Comment: I have never done this and it could take me some time to do so. As I indicated to Ross I made an error with the info I supplied. The column 'LastActiveYear' is not in the 'person' table but in 'membership' table. I feel really bad about giving the wrong information, so sorry. Thank you.

Comment: [**See fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/521736/1) i have created now you have to double check the table names and columns

Comment: I attempted this and made some changes to add the additional table. As I said this is a new resource for me and I'm new at all this. I think Ross has resolved the problem. TNX Vmuch